# Continuity of the derivative on a separated interval

Tags: real-analysis, separable-spaces

Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function that is differentiable on the open interval $(a,c) \cup (c,b)$ for some $c\in [a,b]$. Show that if $\lim_{x\to c} f'(x)$ exists, then $f'(c)$ exists and $f'$ is continuous at $c$.

I'm a measly undergrad so I have very little intuition about this problem. My main point of confusion is this: it seems that even for the points where we know $f'$ exists, there is no guarantee that $f'$ is continuous. So at $c$, we only know that the limit of the derivative exists. To me, this feels like a weaker condition than the derivative itself existing - why should we be able to expect that it is continuous?

Comment: Use the mean-value theorem.  No, you don't expect it to be continuous, but continuity of derivative guarantees its existence at the omitted point.

Comment: @user10354138 But the derivative is not continuous at the omitted point. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f'(x) = L$. You want to show
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}
\end{align}
exists and is equal to $L$. By the mean value theorem, we see that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-L\right| = \left|f'(y)-L \right|
\end{align}
for $x<y<c$ (likewise $x>y>c$ if you are considering the other side limit). If $x$ is close to $c$ then $|f'(y)-L|$ is small (why?). This should prove that $f$ is differentiable at $c$. Using [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29) you should be able to show that $f'$ is continuous.